# How to exclude substring starting with a '(' in case if it exists in regex?

Tags: regex

Regex:

```
([A-Za-z]+),\s([A-Za-z]+)\.\s(.*)[\s\(|\b]
```

Test String:

```
Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath(Lily May Peel)
Heikkinen, Miss. Laina
```

Regex problem screenshot:

[image]

Expected :

- "Jacques Heath" as Capture Group 3 in first line
- "Laina" as Capture Group 3 in second line

Actual:

- "Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)" as Capture Group 3 in first line
- "Laina" as Capture Group 3 in second line

Edit:

**Got what i needed with some modification of answer:**

```
([A-Za-z]+)\,\s*([A-Za-z]+)\.\s*(.*?)(?:\s*\(|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pX5PJ7/2):

[image]

Comment: Try `([A-Za-z]+),\s([A-Za-z]+)\.\s(.*?)(?:\(|$)` or `([A-Za-z]+),\s([A-Za-z]+)\.\s([^(]*)`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pcc2On/1).

Comment: obDontDoThat https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Bingo, it's correct! Add it as answer so i can mark it as correct.

Comment: @NaushadShukoor I have already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `(.*)[\s(|\b]` matches and captures any 0+ chars, as many as possible, up to the last whitespace (`\s`), `(`, `|` or a backspace char. The `[\s(|\b]` is a positive character class where `\b` is not a word boundary, it loses its zero-width meaning there, and `|` is parsed as a literal pipe char.

You may use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) pattern, `[^(]*` (or `[^(]+`):

```
([A-Za-z]+),\s([A-Za-z]+)\.\s([^(]*)
                             ^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pcc2On/1)

To account for a variable amount of whitespace chars, you may use

```
([A-Za-z]+),\s*([A-Za-z]+)\.\s*([^(]*)
            ^^^             ^^^
```

where `\s*` matches 0 or more whitespace chars.